# External javascripts delay load. SCRIPT src attribute doesn't work? Only IFRAME src works

Tags: javascript, iframe, load, delay, onload

I am trying to solve a problem with the `script id="img"` tag. I am using the two of the scripts below on two different pages, but in both cases the script doesn't load.

The IFRAMES are loading perfectly after 5 and 8 seconds in the first example, and both after 5 secs in the second example, and I would like to load js files too, but they are not loaded.

Could anyone help me with this? What do I need to add/modify to the code to make it work? Thanks in advance.

EXAMPLE 1

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function() {
    setTimeout(function(){loadfunction('map','https://www.example1.com/maps/')},5000);
    setTimeout(function(){loadfunction('fbook','https://www.example2.com/')},8000);
    setTimeout(function(){loadfunction('img','https://www.mywebpage.com/img.js')},10000);
}
function loadfunction(id,url) {
    document.getElementById(id).src = url;
} 
</script>
```

The script below does the same thing, but loads them all at the same time 5sec, but not the img.js file, only the iframes.

EXAMPLE 2

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  window.onload = function() {
    setTimeout(loadfunction,5000)
 }
 function loadfunction() {
    document.getElementById("map").src = "https://www.example1.com/maps/"
    document.getElementById("fbook").src = "https://www.example2.com/"
    document.getElementById("img").src = "http://www.mywebpage.com/img.js"
 }
</script>
```

and in the body in both pages I have the code below....

```
<iframe id="map" width="730" height="400" frameborder="0" style="border:0" allowtransparency="true"></iframe> 
<iframe id="fbook" width="730" height="400" frameborder="0" style="border:0" allowtransparency="true"></iframe>
<script id="img" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: It's really not at all clear what you're asking. What is a "script ID function"?

Comment: Hi, well perhaps I didn't express myself properly. I mean the script I am using it doesn't work when I put an ID tag on the script, but it works fine with iframes. I just want to load the img.js with a delay, just like the two iframes, but don't know how?

Comment: Putting an "id" attribute on a `<script>` tag won't really do anything. "Works fine with iframes" is also very confusing. It's really still not clear what you're asking.

Comment: @LavenderBlue Scripts are parsed when a script tag is met. If there's not `src` attribute within a script tag, parser assumes to find the text for the script between tags. If there is an `src` attribute, the script will be loaded, and the content between tags are ignored. Also, scripts are immutable, you can't change the content of an once-parsed script. If you want to load a script with a delay, you have to create a new script tag and set its `src`.

Comment: I did try with a src tag on the script, but it doesn't work. The script loads immediately without a delay. I tried with an empty src="" where the script doesn't load and show and when I try with  src="img.js" the script just loads without the delay?

Comment: Please re-read my comment above. What you are trying to do, is not possible, you can't change the content of a script after it has been parsed. Just create and append a new script to the body after a delay.

Comment: Hi, sorry I am not so good with javascript. Would highly appreciate if you can give me an example how to delay the loading of img,js with let's say 5 seconds. I hope i am not a pain to you and sound stupid. Many thanks. Lisa

Answer (score 0):

Scripts are executed in the order they appear within the HTML code. If `src` is omitted, the content between `script` tags is parsed as a script. If the `src` exists, the script is loaded, and the content between tags is ignored.

Either way you do this, you can't change the content of a script after it has been parsed.

The best way is to create a new script element and give it an `src` property, something like this in `window.onload` handler function:

```
setTimeout(function () {
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = 'https://www.mywebpage.com/img.js';
    document.body.appendChild(script);
}, 10000);
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I have tried this but still doesn't work. I am already using the setTimeout(function with the iframes so when I try to put a separate script for the js file is not working. I don't seem to be able to make it work even on it's own without the iframes. Do I need to include in the body section 

    <script src="https://www.mywebpage.com/img.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

or the script above you recommend will create and parse the https://www.mywebpage.com/img.js into the body?

Comment: @LavenderBlue Yes, it creates a new script to the end of the body. Put the code above into the `window.onload handler`, and [it works](http://jsfiddle.net/k95UQ/).

Comment: I am ever so sorry, looks like as a girl I am not so good at those things :(, did try that and still can't make it to work. Would you be able please to send me the full working script including the two iframes and the img.js all loading with a delay. I would like be able to set different times for loading for each individual iframe and js file. I am sorry to be a pain. Thank you. Lisa

Comment: There's a link to a fiddle in my previous comment. Notice, that `window.onload` is fired after _all_ the resources on a page have been loaded, including the content of the iframes too. Make sure the path set to `src` is correct and the script you load actually works.

Comment: Did try that and still no success. The js file does not appear in the result window. Here is a simple js file from Dynamicdrive website just a text effect: http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex10/topmsg.js when I put this into the code you give on the link, then  Update and Run the js does not appear after 6 seconds as it's stated over there?

Comment: It's definitely the right url: www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex10/topmsg.js

I di so much of research on the internet, and nowhere seem to be able to find the answer for this, which in first instance looks easy to acheive, but it appears that it's not?

Comment: Actually 403... "`Forbidden You don't have permission to access /dynamicindex10/topmsg.js on this server. Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.`"

Comment: Did try the script on my server now with my own js file and still not working, tested on FF Chrome, Opera IE I really thought I have finally find the solution, but :(

Comment: If you're not able to solve it, that's fine I really appreciate your time.

Comment: "`The js file does not appear in the result window`"??? What is "result window"? In my answer there's very well working method for adding scripts dynamically. If it's not working for you, and you have a correct path and a working script at the end of that path, I doubt your script is never executed.

Comment: The result window is the one on the website you pointed out. There are 4 windows there http://jsfiddle.net/k95UQ/ HTML CSS JS and RESULT My img.js contains this: document.write("<img height=\"410\" src=\"images\/footer.png\" width=\"995\" \/>"); and when I run the script, the footer.png does not appear in the result window on the right?

Comment: Oh my... Please read about [`document.write()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.write) to learn, what it does after the page has been parsed ... Also I'm not sure, if `dw()` is still blocked at jsFiddle.

Comment: Ok so you recon the problem is in my JS file because it has document.write() well as I said I am not good with javascript so wouldn't know how to recode the JS file to be able to appear where I want it. I come across with another method, by injecting the script from an IFRAME and just posted my new question, which still has to be answered as there is something there I couldn't work out. Here is my new question, perhaps you'll be able to help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25033294/change-to-content-of-iframe-inject-script-into-iframe-from-another-iframe