# Change to content of IFRAME. Inject script into IFRAME from another IFRAME

Tags: javascript, parsing, iframe, inject

I am working on a script to get and change the content of an IFrame, by accessing a variable and a function defined in it, through a button and a Javascript script created in another IFrame. The script works fine, but what I would like to do is instead of text been injected in the IFRAME 1 I would like to inject a script, something like:

```
<script src="map.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I have tried with injecting IMG and also works:

```
<button onclick="f_ifr2('<img height=\'410\' src=\'images\/footer.png\' width=\'995\' \/>')">
```

.... but I would like to be able to inject a js file something like:

```
<button onclick="f_ifr2('<script src=\'map.js\' type=\'text\/javascript\'><\/script>')">
```

but it doesn't work as something to do with the closing or opening tags < >

Could somebody tell me how to rewrite the:

```
<button onclick="f_ifr2('<script src=\'map.js\' type=\'text\/javascript\'><\/script>')">
```

to avoid the error? Many thanks!

The whole script below:

Code ifr1.htm

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Page for IFrame 1</title>
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
// Stores a value in the variable "var_ifr1", that will be accessed in the second iframe
var var_ifr1 = '<b>Value of the variable from iframe 1</b>';

// Function that replace the content of the DIV "div_ifr1" with the value of its parameter
// It will be called from iframe 2
function f_ifr1(txt) {
  document.getElementById('div_ifr1').innerHTML = txt;
}
//--></script>
</head>
<body>
IFRAME 1
Content in BODY
<div id="div_ifr1">Div content of the iframe 1</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Code ifr2.htm

```
<html>
<head></head>
<title>Page for IFrame 2</title>
<body>
IFRAME 2<br>

<script type="text/javascript"><!--
function f_ifr2(txt) {
  // get the BODY content of the iframe 1, "ifr1"
  var c_ifr1 = parent.ifr1.document.body.innerHTML;

   alert(c_ifr1);          // Displays the content in an alert window

  // gets the value of the variable "var_ifr1", defined in the iframe 1, "ifr1"
  var from_ifr1 = parent.ifr1.var_ifr1;
  // Displays in a tag in this iframe the value of the variable defined in iframe 1
  document.getElementById('d_ifr2').innerHTML = from_ifr1;

  // Calls the function "f_ifr1",  defined in iframe 1
  parent.ifr1.f_ifr1(txt);
}
//--></script>
<div id="d_ifr2"> </div>
<button onclick="f_ifr2('<b>The text changed from iframe 2</b>')">Action iframe</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Code main.html

```
<html>
<head><title>Main Page</title></head>
<body>
<h3>Main Page</h3>
<h4>First iframe</h4>
<iframe src="ifr1.htm" id="ifr1" name="ifr1"></iframe>

<br><h4>Second iframe</h4>
<iframe src="ifr2.htm" id="ifr2" name="ifr2"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try taking out the backslash in `text\/javascript`. The quotes have to be escaped to stop them closing your string, but forward slashes have no special meaning. The browser won't try to load a `script` tag with content it doesn't understand, and "text\/javascript" won't match the expected "text/javascript".

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I did try with:

    '<script src=\'img.js\' type=\'text javascript\'><\/script>'

    '<script src=\'img.js\' type=\'text\ javascript\'><\/script>'

but still nothing?

Comment: `'<script src=\'img.js\' type=\'text/javascript\'>'`, or just use different quotes: `'<script src="img.js" type="text/javascript">'`

Comment: I have tried with your suggestion: '<script src="img.js" type="text/javascript">' and with changing the quotes: '<script src='img.js' type='text/javascript'>' but no success.